# What is the simplest way to play a sample/tone with given tempo in SuperCollider

Tags: audio, frequency, sampling, supercollider, tempo

I'm curious what is the easiest way to play a sound file or some frequency with given tempo. The easiest metronome you can implement. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If it's simplicity you're looking for then the "easiest metronome" is

`~bpm = 120;
x = {Impulse.ar(~bpm/60)}.play;`

but it won't sound very pleasant, and it'll only be in the left channel.

For a tone rather than a click, and in both channels, one simple way is

`~bpm = 120;
x = {SinOsc.ar.dup * Pulse.ar(~bpm/60, 0.01).lag}.play;`

To play back a WAV file, you can simply use a PlayBuf unit and retrigger it at the right tempo. Here we assume you've loaded a sample into a Buffer `b`:

`x = {PlayBuf.ar(1, b, trigger: Impulse.kr(~bpm/60))}.play;`

or alternatively, instead of doing it as a Synth as I did just then, you can put something together using Patterns:

`p = Pseq([Pfunc({ b.play; 60/~bpm })], inf).play`

Comment: Easier than I thought! What about wav samples, would it be much more complicated?

Comment: OK, added that to my answer. If you like the answer pls accept it :)